# Number of ways of selection from a mixed group

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

For example I want to know number of ways I can select $2$ items from $AAABBC$ i,e $3$ of one group,$2$ of other and $1$ of last.

Comment: What is "items"? tuples? subsets? words in the alphabet $\{A,B,C\}$?

Comment: item refer to alphabets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AA, AB, AC, BB, BC

There are 5 options if you want this.

I think there is not general formula for it.

Comment: is there a general formula for this I am looking for a derived formula which works in all cases